# What is wrong with the function shmdt()?

Tags: c, linux, string

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFSZ 2048

int main()
{
    int shmid,i,fd,nwrite,nread;
    char *shmadd;
    char buf[5];
    buf[5] = '\0';

    if((shmid=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,BUFSZ,0x666))<0)
    {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("created shared-memory: %d\n",shmid);

    if((shmadd=shmat(shmid,0,0))<(char *)0)
    {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("attached shared-memory\n");

    shmadd="Hello";

    if((fd = open("share",O_CREAT | O_RDWR,0666))<0)
    {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("open success!\n");

    if((nwrite=write(fd,shmadd,5))<0)
    {
        perror("write");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("write success!\n");

    lseek( fd, 0, SEEK_SET );

    if((nread=read(fd,buf,5))<0)
    {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("read %d form file:%s\n",nread,buf);

    if(close(fd) == -1)
        printf("close fd fails!\n");
    else
        printf("close fd succeeds!\n");

    if((shmdt(shmadd))<0)
    {
        perror("shmdt");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("deleted shared-memory\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

Above is the code which is to demo the shared memory in Linux. And the running result is below:

```
$ ./ex2
created shared-memory: 1572887
attached shared-memory
open success!
write success!
read 5 form file:Hello
close fd succeeds!
shmdt: Invalid argument
```

As you can see, everything goes fine except shmdt(). Why it fails?

***Further：***

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSZ 2048

int main()
{
    int shmid,i,fd,nwrite,nread;
    char *shmadd;
    char buf[5];
    buf[5] = '\0';

    if((shmid=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,BUFSZ,0x666)) < 0)
    {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("created shared-memory: %d\n",shmid);

    if((shmadd=shmat(shmid,0,0)) < (char *)0)
    {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("attached shared-memory\n");

    strcpy(shmadd, "Hello");

    if((fd = open("share",O_CREAT | O_RDWR,0666)) < 0)
    {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("open success!\n");

    if((nwrite=write(fd,shmadd,5)) < 0)
    {
        perror("write");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("write success!\n");

    lseek( fd, 0, SEEK_SET );

    if((nread=read(fd,buf,5)) < 0)
    {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("read %d form file:%s\n",nread,buf);

    if(close(fd) == -1)
        printf("close fd fails!\n");
    else
        printf("close fd succeeds!\n");

    if((shmdt(shmadd))<0)
    {
        perror("shmdt");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("deleted shared-memory\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

Following your answers, I changed the code as above. But now I got new error!

```
$ ./ex2
created shared-memory: 2129948
attached shared-memory
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I seems that strcpy causes the error. But why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
shmadd="Hello";
```

This changes the `shmadd` pointer to point to a string in memory.  I think you intended to copy the string into the shared memory.  To do that, you would do:

```
strcpy(shmadd,"Hello");
```

Also note that your check for errors is wrong, it should be:

```
if((shmadd=shmat(shmid,0,0)) == (void *)-1) { ... error ... }
```

And your permissions should be octal, not hex:

```
if((shmid=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,BUFSZ,0666)) < 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your check for an error with shmadd in this line is incorrect:

```
if((shmadd=shmat(shmid,0,0)) < (char *)0)
```

You need to do an explicit comparison to -1 as per the man page, as a -1 cast to a pointer becomes an unsigned value (0xFFFFFFFF on 32-bit systems).  Replace that line with this one:

```
if((shmadd=shmat(shmid,0,0)) == (char *)-1)
```

and you'll get a permission denied error because you are not root.